# Sending individual email to each client

Tags: apex, email

Hi I am trying to send an individual email to each client so that the greeting is personalised to the account name. I am trying to modify some of my existing code that I have that was originally meant for single use only. Whats coming out is that it is sending an email to the amount of records in opps list but it is including all email addresses for all records in the list in the 'toaddress' for each email. Why is it doing this when I am iterating over the records and assigning toaddress every time? I tried moving `List<String> toAddresses = new List<String>();` to inside the loop but then I receive no email.

```
public class DevelopmentEmail 
{
    public String DevelopId{get;set;}
    public String subject{get;set;}
    public String recipientEmail{get;set;}
    public String partnerEmail{get;set;}
    public String emailBody{get;set;}
    public Boolean sendToPartner{get;set;}
    public Boolean sendToClient{get;set;}
    public String emailNotFoundMessage{get;set;}
    public string emailTemplateBody{get;set;}
    public Opportunity opportunity{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public Set<string> NameSet{get;set;}
    public string DevelopName;
    public List<string> Client1Emails{get;set;}
    public List<string> Client1Names{get;set;}
    public List<string> Client2Emails{get;set;}
    public List<string> Client2Names{get;set;}
    public Development__c dvlp{get;set;}
    public List<Opportunity> opps{get;set;}

    public DevelopmentEmail()
    {
        Client1Emails= New List<String>();
        Client2Emails= New List<String>();
        Client1Names= New List<String>();
        Client2Names= New List<String>();
        DevelopId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');        
        if(String.isNotBlank(DevelopId))
        {    
            opps = [SELECT id,Name, Account.Name, Account.FirstName, Account.LastName, AccountId, Account.PersonEmail, Account.SMSF__c, Account.Partner_First_Name__c, 
                                      Account.Partner_Name__c, Account.Partner_email__c 
                                 FROM   Opportunity 
                                 WHERE  Development__c =: DevelopId];
            List<Development__c> dvlplist = [Select Id, Name from Development__c where Id =: DevelopId];
            dvlp = dvlplist[0];
            if(opps != null && opps.size() > 0)
            {
                for(Opportunity opp : opps){
                    //opportunity = opps[0];
                    emailNotFoundMessage = 'Email address not found.';
                    if(String.isNotBlank(opp.Account.Partner_email__c))
                    {
                        Client2Emails.add(opp.Account.Partner_email__c); 
                        //partnerEmail = opportunity.Account.Partner_email__c;
                    }
                    system.debug('partner email==='+partnerEmail);
                    system.debug('client1 email==='+opp.Account.PersonEmail);
                    if(String.isNotBlank(opp.Account.PersonEmail))
                    {
                        Client1Emails.add(opp.Account.PersonEmail); 
                        //recipientEmail = opp.Account.PersonEmail;
                    } 
                    Client1Names.add(opp.Account.Name);
                    if(String.isNotBlank(opp.Account.Partner_Name__c)){
                        Client2Names.add(opp.Account.Partner_Name__c);
                    }
                    Name = opp.Account.Name;


                }

                system.debug('client1emails ==='+Client1Emails);
                String templateName = 'Development Update';
                List<EmailTemplate> emailTemplate = DevelopmentEmail_Handler.getEmailTemplate(templateName);
                system.debug('EMAILTEMPLATE==='+emailTemplate);
                system.debug('client email==='+recipientEmail);
                if(emailTemplate != null && emailTemplate.size() > 0 )
                {
                    DevelopName = dvlp.Name;
                    subject = 'Development Update - ' + DevelopName;
                    if(emailTemplate[0].HTMLValue != null)
                    {
                        emailTemplateBody = emailTemplate[0].HTMLValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //This method uploads the file in to Attachment object under the development record.
    @RemoteAction
    public static Object uploadfileAttachment(String attachmentName, String attachmentBody, string attchmentContent, String DevelopId)
    {
         system.debug(DevelopId);
         system.debug(attachmentName);
         system.debug(attachmentBody);
         system.debug(attchmentContent);

         Development__c dvlp = getdevelop(DevelopId);
         if(dvlp != null) 
         {
            if(String.isNotBlank(attachmentBody) )
            {
                 Attachment att = new Attachment();
                 att.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(attachmentBody);
                 att.Name = 'Development Update Attachment - '+attachmentName;
                 att.parentId = DevelopId;
                 att.contentType = attchmentContent;
                 insert att;
                 List<Attachment> attachments = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachment 
                                                 WHERE parentid =:DevelopId 
                                                 AND Name LIKE 'Development Update Attachment - %' LIMIT 50000];
                 return attachments;
            }
            else 
            {
                return 'Attachment Body was null';
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            return 'Development could not be found';
        }
    }
    public pageReference sendEmailAction2() 
    {   
        try
        {

            List<String> toAddresses = new List<String>();
            system.debug(sendToPartner+'---'+sendToClient+'----'+emailBody);
             Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
             Messaging.Email[] listemails = new List<Messaging.Email>();
             List<Attachment> allAttachment = new List<Attachment>();
             allAttachment = [SELECT Id, Name, ContentType,body FROM Attachment 
                              WHERE parentid =: DevelopId
                              AND   Name LIKE 'Development Update Attachment - %'];
             system.debug('alattach'+allAttachment.size());
            // Create the email attachment
             List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> efaList = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
            //cycle through each opp for individual 
            for(Opportunity opp : opps){
                system.debug(opp.Account.PersonEmail);
                //Sets the paramaters of the email
                if( sendToClient && opp.Account.PersonEmail != null)
                {
                    toAddresses.add(opp.Account.PersonEmail);
                }
                if( sendToPartner && opp.Account.Partner_Email__c != null)
                {
                    toAddresses.add(opp.Account.Partner_Email__c);
                }
                email.setSubject(subject);
                email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                if(String.isNotBlank(emailBody))
                {
                    emailTemplateBody = emailTemplateBody.replace('[COMMENTS INSERTED HERE]', emailBody);
                }
                else
                {
                    emailTemplateBody = emailTemplateBody.replace('[COMMENTS INSERTED HERE]', '');
                }
                email.setHTMLBody(emailTemplateBody);
                listemails.add(email);
            }
                //create the activity record
                task tsk =  DevelopmentEmail_Handler.createActivity('Development Update - '+DevelopName,emailTemplateBody.replaceAll('<[^>]+>','').unescapeHtml4(),DevelopId,null);
                List<Attachment> taskAttachments = new List<Attachment>();
                if(allAttachment != null && allAttachment.size()> 0)
                {    
                    for(integer i=0; i < allAttachment.size(); i++)
                    { 
                        Attachment attach = new Attachment();
                        attach.Body = allAttachment[i].body;
                        attach.Name = allAttachment[i].Name;
                        if(attach.Name.startsWith('Development Update Attachment - '))
                        {
                            attach.Name = attach.Name.removeStart('Development Update Attachment - ');
                        }
                        attach.parentId = tsk.id;
                        attach.contentType = allAttachment[i].ContentType;
                        taskAttachments.add(attach);
                    }
                    insert taskAttachments;
                    if(taskAttachments != null && taskAttachments.size()> 0)
                     {
                        for (Integer i = 0; i < taskAttachments.size(); i++)
                        {
                            system.debug(taskAttachments[i].Name);
                            Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
                            efa.setFileName(taskAttachments[i].Name);
                            efa.setBody(taskAttachments[i].Body);
                            efa.setContentType(taskAttachments[i].ContentType);
                            efaList.add( efa );
                        }
                        email.setFileAttachments(efaList );
                     }
                }
                //    listemails.add(email);


            system.debug('Develop-id'+DevelopId); 
            system.debug('emailTemplate-body===='+emailTemplateBody);
            // Sends the email
            //
            //Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email}); 
            Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(listemails); 
            delete allAttachment; 
            return new PageReference('/'+DevelopId).setRedirect(True);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            system.debug(e.getMessage()+'---'+e.getLineNumber());
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,e.getMessage());
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static Development__c getdevelop(string dvlpid)
    {
        list<Development__c> dvlps = [select id,name from Development__c where Id =:dvlpid ];
        if(dvlps != null && dvlps.size() > 0)
        {
            return dvlps[0];
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    @RemoteAction
    public static String getEmailBody(String DevelopId) 
    {
        if(String.isNotBlank(DevelopId))
        {
            String templateName = 'Development Update';
            List<EmailTemplate> emailTemplate = DevelopmentEmail_Handler.getEmailTemplate(templateName);
            if(emailTemplate != null && emailTemplate.size() > 0)
            {
                return emailTemplate[0].HTMLValue;
            }
            else
            {
                return '100-'+templateName;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return '101-Development ID not found.';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you did not clear the `toAddresses` list so it store old values as well and you get all emails in the list. So you need to update your for loop as

```
for(Opportunity opp : opps){
    // add these two lines inside for loop
    List<String> toAddresses = new List<String>();
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    ......
```

Also you need to handle your code where you add attachments to email.

Comment: Hey Tushar, thanks for that. I only tried moved list<String>..., moving the Messaging.Single.... line as well fixed my problem. I am aware the attachments now need to be cleaned up too, was just trying to fix this issue first thanks.